# compare 2 xml nodesets in same xml and come up with a resultant xml

Tags: xslt

I have an xml with 2 different node sets in it. I need a comparison between them and pick up the values as needed in result.

## Request

```
<MyMessage>
  <EmployeeLookup>
    <EmployeeQuery>
      <MsgId>XXX</MsgId>
      <LookupValues>
        <LookupValue>
          <Name>SSN</Name>
          <Value>123456</Value>
        </LookupValue>
        <LookupValue>
          <Name>DrivingLicense</Name>
          <Value>AA-234-123</Value>
        </LookupValue>
      </LookupValues>
    </EmployeeQuery>
    <EmployeeQuery>
      <MsgId>YYY</MsgId>
      <LookupValues>
        <LookupValue>
          <Name>DrivingLicense</Name>
          <Value>BB-494-432</Value>
        </LookupValue>
      </LookupValues>
    </EmployeeQuery>
    <EmployeeQuery>
      <MsgId>ZZZ</MsgId>
      <LookupValues>
        <LookupValue>
          <Name>SSN</Name>
          <Value>fakessn</Value>
        </LookupValue>
      </LookupValues>
    </EmployeeQuery>
  </EmployeeLookup>
  <KnownEmployees>
    <Employee>
      <eno>101</eno>
      <SSN>123456</SSN>
      <DrivingLicense>AA-234-123</DrivingLicense>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
      <eno>102</eno>
      <SSN>456677</SSN>
      <DrivingLicense>BB-494-432</DrivingLicense>
    </Employee>
  </KnownEmployees>
</MyMessage>
```

## Result needed

```
<CombinedResult>
  <Employee>
    <MsgId>XXX</MsgId>
    <RetrievedIds>
      <Identifier>
        <Name>eno</Name>
        <Value>101</Value>
      </Identifier>
    </RetrievedIds>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <MsgId>YYY</MsgId>
    <RetrievedIds>
      <Identifier>
        <Name>eno</Name>
        <Value>102</Value>
      </Identifier>
    </RetrievedIds>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <MsgId>ZZZ</MsgId>
    <RetrievedIds />
  </Employee>
</CombinedResult>
```

We need to retrieve the employee number (eno) based on the lookup values such as SSN, DrivingLicense number. They can be 1 to n. We need to retrieve based on **any** of the provided lookup values.

I tried defining a key like

```
<xsl:key name="MyKey" match="//Employee" use="*" />
```

That works.. but it fails if two keys have the same value.

So, I tried doing

```
<xsl:key name="MyKey" match="//Employee" use="concat(local-name(*),'|',.)" />
```

But in that case, it is matching only the first field i.e. Employee/SSN

Can some guide me here.. I am open to any approach if not the xsl:key way.

Comment: can you include the code you are having issues with?

Comment: Welcome to SO. To be able to help you properly, please provide a [mcve] as outlined in [ask]. If you don't know how to do that, at least share your efforts, so we can tell you where you are wrong.

Comment: I am posting on this below.. sorry for the delay in response

Answer (score 0):

> So, I tried doing
>
> `<xsl:key name="MyKey" match="//Employee"
>   use="concat(local-name(*),'|',.)" />`

I believe you need to define the key as:

```
<xsl:key name="emp" match="Employee/*" use="concat(local-name(), .)" />
```

Then, when you call the key, you must call it with a node-set (XSLT 1.0) or a sequence (XSLT 2.0) of all given lookup values, each concatenating its name and value.

Note that at least in theory it's possible for two lookup values within the same `EmployeeQuery` to match two different employees.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working after following your suggestion and making changes to the other part of the script. This is the final script that worked for me.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/MyMessage" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/MyMessage">
    <CombinedResult>
      <xsl:for-each select="EmployeeLookup/EmployeeQuery">
        <Employee>
          <MsgId>
            <xsl:value-of select="MsgId/text()" />
          </MsgId>
          <RetrievedIds>
            <xsl:call-template name="MyUniqueIdTemplate" />
          </RetrievedIds>
        </Employee>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </CombinedResult>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:key name="MyKey" match="//Employee/*" use="concat(local-name(),'|',.)" />
  <xsl:template name="MyUniqueIdTemplate">
  <xsl:if test="count(key('MyKey', concat(LookupValues/LookupValue/Name,'|',LookupValues/LookupValue/Value))) &gt; 0">
    <Identifier>
      <Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="&quot;eno&quot;" />
      </Name>
      <Value>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('MyKey', concat(LookupValues/LookupValue/Name,'|',LookupValues/LookupValue/Value))/../eno" />
      </Value>      
    </Identifier>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you for the tip

Comment: HI Michael et al,
I found a loophole in the method i.e.
`concat(LookupValues/LookupValue/Name,'|',LookupValues/LookupValue/Value)`

is matching the first Name/Value pair and fetching it. If I deliberately changed my first Name/Value pair, it doesn't match anymore even though the second Name/Value pair matches it. 

How to get around this situation where you would like to match 1 or all.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: To quote an example, for the first record
SSN = 123456 and DL = AA-234-123.
If I manipulate my input xml to make SSN=123, then it is not matching with the KnownEmployees/Employee anymore.

However, if I change the DL leaving the SSN as-is, it matches.

How to write in such a way...
1. Atleast one of the LookupValues should match without the side-effect of get the record multiple times if there is more than one LookupValue that gets matched.
2. Ensure all the LookupValues match.